# Difference between a 'medicine' and a 'medicinal'

Tags: differences, nouns

What is the exact difference between the words "medicine" and "medicinal"?

For *medicinal*, [Free Dictionary](http://thefreedictionary.com/medicinal) states:

> "A preparation or product having the properties of a medicine."

But the fact is that a "medicine" is itself a "preparation" or "product" which has curative properties. Is there any particular reason for making a noun out of this adjective?

Comment: The OED gives a usage of "medicinal" as a noun, as early as 1382.  I suspect that any reason for the coining of this noun may be lost in the mists of time.

Comment: Medicine is a noun, while medicinal is an adjective.

Comment: ...and while both can be used in each other's contexts (took a medicinal, medicine man), one is primarily a noun, the other primarily adjective.

Comment: I would understand the use of "medicinal" as a noun when referring to a product accepted by alternative medical practices, but not by mainstream medicine.

Comment: Sure.  This would be the case in jurisdictions where there is legislation governing what may be labelled a "medicine".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the noun/adjective difference already mentioned, I would say the main difference (in modern usage) between a medicine and a medicinal is that a medicine's primary, inherent use is as a curative. A medicinal, on the other hand, is a substance that is being pressed into service as a curative - it may not normally be viewed as a medicine.

For instance:

- an antibiotic is a medicine
- a shot of brandy could be a medicinal, if given to treat shock, etc. (not that that's necessarily a good idea!)

That's the main difference in my mind, but feel free to disagree!

Comment: Welcome to the site.  It's certainly a good theory.